# Зачем здесь кавычки?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Первая "игровая экранизация" Pokemon GO от легендарной студии Brazzers!

Comment: Вот... и сюда покемоны добрались ;)

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, вопрос с подвохом) Учитывая специфическую деятельность студии Brazzers, можно предположить, что в этом контексте *игровая экранизация* значит не совсем то, что обычно (ср. недавно вышедший фильм "Варкрафт", который был действительно игровой экранизацией).

Есть правило, согласно которому слова, употребляемые в переносном или нестандартном значении, берутся в кавычки. Здесь оно и проявляется.

Answer (score 0):

Бессмысленно гадать, не имея контекста. Скорее всего просто редактор умничает. 
Я что-то плохо представляю, какой переносный смысл можно вложить в закавыченное сочетание. А если даже он и есть, одних кавычек для такого использования мало. Надо еще, чтобы предполагаемое значение было понятно хотя бы по контексту.